# Loaded event is not fired for newly set content of ContentControl after it has been fully loaded

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to be able to bind `Content` property of `ContentPresenter` to a ViewModel property, so that when ViewModel changes the value of its property, `Content` of `ContentPresenter` is determined based on `DataTemplate` and `Loaded` event is fired for newly rendered View (that is chosen based on `DataTemplate`). Following code example demonstrates the problem, which is, `Loaded` event is not fired when `Content` is changed.

As far as I understand `Loaded` event is not fired when `Content` of `ContentPresenter` is changed and I'm OK with that. The problem is that `Loaded` event for newly loaded context is not fired, but it gets rendered nonetheless. Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

**MainWindow**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfLoadProblem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfLoadProblem"
        Height="450"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ContentViewModel}">
            <local:ContentUserControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Command="{Binding Path=ChangeContentCommand}" Grid.Row="0">Change Content</Button>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Content}" Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindowViewModel**

```
internal sealed class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private object content;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ChangeContentCommand = new DelegateCommand(ChangeContent);
    }

    public ICommand ChangeContentCommand { get; }

    public object Content
    {
        get => content;
        private set
        {
            if (content != value)
            {
                content = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Content)));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void ChangeContent()
    {
        // After setting this property Loaded event is not fired for the 2nd and consecutive times.
        Content = new ContentViewModel();
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

**ContentUserControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfLoadProblem.ContentUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;assembly=Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger x:Name="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=LoadedCommand}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Numbers}"/>
</UserControl>
```

**ContentViewModel**

```
internal sealed class ContentViewModel
{
    private readonly ICollection<int> numbers = new ObservableCollection<int>();

    public ContentViewModel()
    {
        LoadedCommand = new DelegateCommand(Load);
    }

    public ICommand LoadedCommand { get; }

    public IEnumerable<int> Numbers => numbers;

    private void Load()
    {
        int start = numbers.Count == 0 ? 0 : numbers.Max();

        numbers.Clear();

        for (int number = start; number < start + 5; ++number)
        {
            numbers.Add(number);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Loaded` event won't be fired unless the control is unloaded. And it's not when the `Content` changes. The applied `DateTemplate` is cached and only the data context and bindings are updated.

Instead of relying on the `Loaded` event being raised, you should invoke the `LoadedCommand` or call `Load()` directly in your call `ChangeContent()` method right after you have set the `Content` property:

```
private void ChangeContent()
{
    var viewModel = = new ContentViewModel();
    Content = viewModel;
    viewModel.LoadedCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

Comment: Well, that's the closest to achieving what I want without any extra hackery. Thank you, I'll mark this as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but since the type of `Content` never changes, it's possible that the `DataTemplate` being used never changes either. Instead, it just continues to use the same `DataTemplate`. What *would* change, though, would be the `DataContext`. Try using the [`DataContextChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontextchanged) event instead of `Loaded` and see if that works.

Comment: Actually, that is kind of true, because if I set different type of view models on different execution of command it works. But if I set them one after another to sort of "reset" data template it still doesn't work. I guess it has something to do with when exactly it chooses to reuse the existing data template. `DataContextChanged` is good but not really solves my problem, because it has to be set on `ContentPresenter` but `Loaded` is set on `UserControl` that is set as its content.

Comment: I guess, as a really nasty workaround, when `DataContextChanged` event it fired for `ContentPresenter` it should call something like `Loaded` on its content.

Comment: @PavelDubsky I was assuming (hoping) that `DataContextChanged` would propagate down the tree.